# Unable to SSH to Ubuntu host while running Android Emulator and using JSch

Tags: android, ssh

I am using JSch to connect to a host (Ubuntu) machine. I can SSH to myself `ssh dev@localhost` without any issues from the terminal. This is the JSch code I am running inside of my Android app.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class PortForwardingR{
  public static void main(String[] arg){

    int rport=9999;
    String lhost="localhost";
    int lport=22;
    String user="dev";
    String host="10.90.111.148";
    String pw = "password";
    
    try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();

      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, lport);
      
      session.setPassword(pw);
      session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      
      session.connect();

      session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport);

      System.out.println(host+":"+rport+" -> "+lhost+":"+lport);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

If I run this same code on my Windows machine in Eclipse, it connects to my Ubuntu without issue. If I run this inside of my Android studio app on my Ubuntu I get:

```
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 22) from /:: (port 58380): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

If I drop into a ADB Shell on my Android device I can ping 10.0.2.2. I know port 22 (SSH) is listening from a netstat and I can connect from Windows using the same code. I have also tried using `dbclient` which is a ssh client. I can run the command:

```
./dbclient dev@10.0.2.2
```

And I get the error:

```
./dbclient Warning: failed to identify current user. Trying anyway.

./dbclient: Connection to dev@10.0.2.2:22 exited: Connect failed: Connection refused
```

I am lost at why this is happening. I am able to run this same code on another machine that connects to the local host (Ubuntu). What should I be looking for or what should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the emulator it started to work correctly.